# Using Spring AMQP consumer in spring-webflux

Tags: spring-amqp, project-reactor

I have an app that's using Boot 2.0 with webflux, and has an endpoint returning a Flux of `ServerSentEvent`. The events are created by leveraging `spring-amqp` to consume messages off a RabbitMQ queue. My question is: How do I best bridge the `MessageListener`'s configured listener method to a Flux that can be passed up to my controller?

Project Reactor's [create](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create) section mentions that it "can be very useful to bridge an existing API with the reactive world - such as an asynchronous API based on listeners", but I'm unsure how to hook into the message listener directly since it's wrapped in the `DirectMessageListenerContainer` and `MessageListenerAdapter`. Their example from the create section:

```
Flux<String> bridge = Flux.create(sink -> {
    myEventProcessor.register( 
      new MyEventListener<String>() { 

        public void onDataChunk(List<String> chunk) {
          for(String s : chunk) {
            sink.next(s); 
          }
        }

        public void processComplete() {
            sink.complete(); 
        }
    });
});
```

So far, the best option I have is to create a `Processor` and simply call `onNext()` each time in the RabbitMQ listener method to manually produce an event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class AmqpToWebfluxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(AmqpToWebfluxApplication.class, args);

        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = applicationContext.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("foo", "event-" + i);
        }

    }

    private TopicProcessor<String> sseFluxProcessor = TopicProcessor.share("sseFromAmqp", Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE);

    @GetMapping(value = "/sseFromAmqp", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> getSeeFromAmqp() {
        return this.sseFluxProcessor;
    }

    @RabbitListener(id = "fooListener", queues = "foo")
    public void handleAmqpMessages(String message) {
        this.sseFluxProcessor.onNext(message);
    }

}
```

The `TopicProcessor.share()` allows to have many concurrent subscribers which we get when we return this `TopicProcessor` as a `Flux` to our `/sseFromAmqp` REST request via WebFlux.

The `@RabbitListener` just delegates its received messages to that `TopicProcessor`.

In the `main()` I have a code to confirm that I can publish to the `TopicProcessor` even if there is no subscribers.

Tested with two separate `curl` sessions and published messages to the queue via RabbitMQ Management Plugin.

By the way I use `share()` because of: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_topicprocessor

> from multiple upstream Publishers when created in the shared configuration

That' because that `@RabbitListener` really can be called from different `ListenerContainer` threads, concurrently.

**UPDATE**

Also I moved this sample to my `Sandbox`: https://github.com/artembilan/sendbox/tree/master/amqp-to-webflux

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I noticed in the reactor docs it states "Most of the time, you should try to avoid using a Processor. They are harder to use correctly and prone to some corner cases...Could a "generator" operator work instead?". Given that, Is there a benefit to using a Processor over a Flux `create` here? I noticed you switched to a UnicastProcessor in your sandbox project.

Comment: Right, I did. That was a recommendation from Reactor team. They are going to remove/replace `Topic/WorkQueue` in the next version. for the proper solution we have to wait for the Reactor RabbitMQ project anyway: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-rabbitmq

Comment: @ArtemBilan so if it was a dynamic topic (say, per user) would you keep a `Map<String, TopicProcessor>` ?

Comment: I think so. There is no choice

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you want to have a single RabbitMQ listener that somehow puts messages to one or more `Flux`(es). `Flux.create` is indeed a good way how to create such a `Flux`.

Let's start with [Messaging with RabbitMQ](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq) Spring guide and try to adapt it.

The original `Receiver` would have to be modified in order to be able to put received messages to a `FluxSink`.

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    /**
     * Collection of sinks enables more than one subscriber.
     * Have to keep in mind that the FluxSink instance that the emitter works with, is provided per-subscriber.
     */
    private final List<FluxSink<String>> sinks = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Adds a sink to the collection. From now on, new messages will be put to the sink.
     * Method will be called when a new Flux is created by calling Flux.create method.
     */  
    public void addSink(FluxSink<String> sink) {
        sinks.add(sink);
    }

    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        sinks.forEach(sink -> {
            if (!sink.isCancelled()) {
                sink.next(message);
            } else {
                // If canceled, don't put any new messages to the sink.
                // Sink is canceled when a subscriber cancels the subscription.
                sinks.remove(sink);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now we have a receiver that puts RabbitMQ messages to sink. Then, creating a `Flux` is rather simple.

```
@Component
public class FluxFactory {

    private final Receiver receiver;

    public FluxFactory(Receiver receiver) { this.receiver = receiver; }

    public Flux<String> createFlux() {
        return Flux.create(receiver::addSink);
    }
}
```

`Receiver` bean is autowired to the factory. Of course, you don't have to create a special factory. This only demonstrates the idea how to use the `Receiver` to create the `Flux`.

The rest of the application from [Messaging with RabbitMQ](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq) guide may stay the same, including the bean instantiation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    ...
    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }
    ...
}
```

I used similar design to adapt Twitter streaming API sucessfuly. Though, there may be a nicer way how to do it.

Comment: See my answer also

Comment: @ArtemBilan Nice tip. Thank you.